# Is a term stating the contract can only be changed in writing, valid?

Tags: contract-law

For example https://www.lawinsider.com/clause/no-modification

> No Modification. This Agreement may be changed only by a writing
>   signed by both parties.

I know a contract is still binding without a signature, and even if it's not in writing. So are these types of terms enforceable?

Answer (score 2):

### Absolutely

Clauses requiring variations to be in writing are common and enforceable.

Of course, the parties can agree verbally to vary that clause - but if they agree it was varied, why are they in dispute?

Comment: I don't understand the conclusion made by your last point. If parties verbally agreed that verbal agreements were allowed, then a dispute arises about a future verbal agreement, hypothetically it would be easier for one party to argue that a verbal agreements were never valid anyway.

Comment: @justasking111 correct. If the parties make a verbal change and one party then welches (some people are unscrupulous, shocking, isn’t it?j then that party can rely on this clause to exclude the verbal agreement absent any other evidence of it.

Answer (score 1):

It varies by jurisdiction. In Colorado, such terms are completely invalid. Some jurisdictions honor them.

Comment: That is interesting I wouldn't have expected that.. Is that a matter of statute, or case law?

Comment: @DavidSiegel Long standing case law.